# If any, what would be the ideal modulation frequency for a phase-sensitive light sensing experiment in a non-dark environment?

Tags: optics, experimental-physics

I have constructed some equipment for sensing a beam of light. The equipment is enclosed in a rudimentary darkbox to block out the majority of the ambient room lighting, but is still partially exposed. In order to isolate the beam from the ambient lighting we are modulating the beam with an optical chopper and sensing it with a phase-sensitive detector (lock-in amplifier).

I'm trying to identify the ideal modulation frequency of the chopper in order to avoid sources of noise in the environment. So far I have tried to avoid multiples of 60 Hz to account for the electrical lines and fluorescent lighting in the room. I have tried using 1039 Hz on the basis of it being a prime number, but the ambient lighting is clearly still having some influence, because the reading changes significantly depending on how open/closed the darkbox is. This may not be an issue of modulation frequency at all; maybe it has something to do with the dynamic reserve of the lock-in amplifier.

I'm hoping someone around here might have worked with a similar set up before and can inform from their experience.

Comment: It may also have to do with the response of the detector - if the ambient light is saturating the detector, the lock in doesn't have much of anything to work with. Years ago I did transient reflectivity experiments using a near-IR laser diode and a silicon photodiode. Using a 4-pole Chebyshev low pass filter set to block anything above 20Hz I could do the experiments with the room lights on, but did have to shield the photodiode from directly seeing the room lights to prevent overloading it. So, look at your detector signal before the lock-in and see if it is maxed out.

Comment: I was wondering about that... It is a possibility. Will keep this in mind, thanks.

Comment: FYI, my detector is a photomultiplier tube. I have seen it behave non-linearly as a result of receiving too intense a signal, but I would not know how to identify an overload.

Comment: How you set up the PM tube impacts the output (OK, not surprising). Are you set up for DC (proportional) mode or photon counting (pulsed) mode? What is the max signal output voltage? Put a voltmeter on it - if it is near the max with no signal from your experiment you have a problem. Then, turn out all the lights and see what the signal is with max light from your experiment. Compare.

Comment: Taking a voltmeter to it is a good idea. Having the lock-in amplifier as the only measurement tool can be confusing, because it will only give a reading for the lock. I will remove the lock-in for the time being and see if I can deduce some things about where the pmt saturates with a simple voltmeter.

Answer (score 1):

The psd method basically moves the signal from d.c. to some other frequency, and then is sensitive to noise at that other frequency. Therefore you pick a frequency where the noise is small. Many noise sources decrease with frequency, so often one picks as high a frequency as your detector and de-modulation stage (usually a lock-in amplifier) can handle.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to a dynamic signal analyzer or similar?  My most recent setup involves locking in to a signal from a split photodiode that is either singly or doubly modulated.  We chose our base modulation frequency by looking at the noise spectrum -- our photodiode when illuminated with a DC signal looks something like this:

[image]

There's a ton of low-frequency noise including 60 Hz main noise and few-Hz from mechanical vibrations in our system.  If the fluorescent lights are on we sometimes see signals at strange frequencies from those.  The way we are doing our modulation scales poorly beyond about 10 kHz, so that was an upper limit.  Because of this, we run our signal through a high-pass preamp with 12 dB/octave falloff.  Then the signal response looks like

[image]

and we modulate at around 5 kHz which is safely above the high-pass but not so high that we lose modulation power.  This might be overkill for your situation however, it's hard to say.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think I have access to something like that. Good idea, though. 

I may have to just do the brute-force method. The lock-in amplifiers have a noise setting, so I can just try to pinpoint the modulation frequency with the lowest noise, by looking at different frequencies one-by-one.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it seems that your detection system is operating in a nonlinear region.  Nonlinearities in the detection system will complicate things, so making sure the detector is operating in its linear range will be very important.  If the detection is linear, separation of the ambient and signal beam effects should be fairly straightforward.  A useful approach can be to directly measure the ambient light that leaks into your box.  You can then find a way to separate the effects of your light beam and the ambient light.